# Couldn't Cast Value of Type UIButton: Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting this error of cannot cast the value of type UIButton in the console. The thing is that this is not a UIButton, it is a label[image]

[image]

Would anyone one know why?

Comment: Check if you added the right tag and also try `cell.contentView.viewWithTag...`

Comment: This did not work...

Comment: before compiling try Cleaning[ Window + shift + k] your project And reopen it and rebuild

Comment: Basically don't use `viewWithTag()` in a table view / collection view cell. This is pretty old-fashioned. Use a **custom** cell, subclass `UITableViewCell` / `UICollectionViewCell` and use IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ViewWithTag(2)` is not `label`. Check if you are adding `button` programmatically inside your `cell` and setting the tag `Value 2`.

> Also try to avoid forced unwrapped if possible to prevent the crash

```
guard let questionLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel else {return}
questionLabel.text = "yourValue
```

Comment: I checked the tags it was the only with tag 2. I tried to do the guard let but gave me this error: non void function should return a value

Comment: Ok not very sure need to look your complete code. But can you try setting different tag value for eg 99?